# Dust particles seen through viewfider

Tags: nikon-d3100, dust

I have a very interesting thing happening with my Nikon D3100.  When I look through the view finder I can see very prominent dust particles all over the frame.  I know it is not dust on the sensor because these particles do not appear in any photos taken.  I have opened the camera and used the hand blower, q-tips with a small amount of alcohol, etc and cleaned the mirror, sensor, lenses, viewfinder (on the outside anyways) and practically everything I can find that seems to be a part of imaging and no matter what I do, those particles remain there unmoved and unaffected.

Where in the world are they and how do I remove them?

Answer (score 2):

on the focusing screen, probably. if you can't remove them, don't worry, they'll not show up on your photos.

if you dare, you can follow [these instructions](http://www.focusingscreen.com/work/d5100en.htm) to remove it for cleaning.

Comment: They are VERY annoying while taking pictures.  I have even considered taking into a shop to be cleaned but I imagine the cost would be ridiculous.

Comment: @MikeV see my update

Comment: I will give this a try to clean the focusing screen and hopefully I will be able to remove these things.

Comment: Just me, but don't touch the focus screen unless you're prepared to replace it. Matte plastic is very very easily scratched/rubbed--I've done it with microfiber cloths, let alone cotton swabs. Try a bulb blower aimed at the "ceiling" of the chamber, with the camera held face-to-the-floor first.